# Decoding Result Struct from tryAggregate3 Multicall3 with web3.py

Tags: python, struct, calldata, multicall, decode

Hello Ethereum StackExchange community,

I'm currently working with the Multicall3 contract's tryAggregate3 function which returns an array of Result structs with the following format:

```
struct Result {
    bool success;
    bytes returnData;
}
```

When interacting with this contract using ethers.js, I can successfully decode the returned data like so:

```
coder = new ethers.utils.AbiCoder(); 
data = "<your_data_here>"; // replaced for brevity
decodedData = coder.decode(
    [ { type: "tuple[]", components: [
        { name: "success", type: "bool" },
        { name: "returnData", type: "bytes" }
    ] } ],
    data
);
```

However, I am facing difficulties achieving the same result with web3.py. I have attempted to use the eth_abi library to decode the Result struct, but without success.

Can someone guide me on how to properly decode such structs with web3.py or provide a snippet of Python code that would mimic the above ethers.js functionality?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!